# What limit "identities" are good to memorize for early college calculus?

Tags: limits

I don't know if "identity" is the correct word, but this would be an example: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^{x} = e $$

With my current knowledge, I wouldn't really know where to begin in solving this, so whenever I see this notation (or something similar like $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{x} \right)^{x} = \frac{1}{e} $), I know I'm dealing with some form of $e$ (if that makes sense).

Other properties I have memorized are for example what the limit of $\arctan$ is (even though I could simply visualize it, we can't using graphing calculators on the exam and I'm very bad at sketching more complex functions), or that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a}{x} \sin{x} = a$. I also just learned about the [Stirling approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603159/how-do-i-compute-the-following-limit-lim-x-to-infty-fracx-left-fr/1603178?noredirect=1#comment3266641_1603178) from another user here.

Are there any other noticeable limits like these that I should be on lookout for?

Comment: 'noticeable identities like these' -i.e. limits?

Comment: @Alex Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: @AndresStadelmann, have you memorized math ;p.

Comment: You can't 'keep on lookout for' stuff like this (if I got you right), but you can keep working on Calc/Analysis, and you will find many other

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Not quite...

Comment: My fav: $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{a^t -1}{t} = \ln a$

Comment: @Alex Damn that looks impressive, thanks!

Comment: @AndresStadelmann the result actual comes from the definition of the derivative for $f(t)=a^t$.

Comment: @zz20s From my experience (exercises given in class) whenever you can apply the definition of the derivative to solve a limit you can also apply L'Hospital, is this also the case here?

Comment: That is correct, as the definition of a derivative gives an indeterminate form. However, this is a circular argument because L'Hopital implies that you have defined the derivatives of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: this is not an answer. I just didn't want to deal with writing latex in the comments.*

A few off the top of my head are $\lim_{x\to 0} {\dfrac{sinx}{x}} = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}{\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1}$

Also $\lim_{x \to a}{(1+\dfrac{1}{f(x)})^{f(x)} = e}$ and $\lim_{x \to a}({\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}})^{h(x)} = e^{\lim_{x \to a}{h(x)(\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 1)}}$

Comment: I've seen the proof of why $\lim_{x\to 0} {\dfrac{sinx}{x}} = 1$ and subsequently $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{sin{\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$. I've always wondered how $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{sin{\frac{a}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}} = a$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to 0} {\dfrac{sinx}{\frac{x}{a}}} = a$...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

From the other user !!

$$A= \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^{x}$$ $$\log(A)=x\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)$$ Now, remember that when $y$ is small $\log(1+y)\approx y$ Replace $y$ by $\frac 1x$ and you are done.

What you must know, remember and use are Taylor series for the basic functions.

Comment: especially for $e^x and \sin(x)$ !!!!

Comment: @S.Mo. Plus many other ! I started being in love with Taylor series almost 60 years ago. Back to serious, it is more important to know how to build them from scratch (which is quite easy). But memorizing some of them is really crucial.

Comment: I need to learn how to make Taylor series by myself since my professor failed to finish the curriculum (I feel stupid only telling myself this now). From what I understand it is an approximation of a function by adding other simpler functions (kind of what the Fourier series does with trig functions - why I learned this before, don't ask me), but how does this help to solve limits?

Comment: @AndresStadelmann. It is just a polynomial expansion built around a value. Then, you baiscally have to consider how behaves the ratio of two polynomials close to a point. Then, the limit is simple. Look in this site; there are thousands of applications.

Comment: @AndresStadelmann Taylor series helps you to solve limits because it allows you to sort of play with a function when its limit is otherwise indeterminate.

Comment: It took me a day, but I realize now that you were giving me a hint for how to solve $\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^{x}$. Thanks so much! I have another question regarding Taylor series (which are indeed pretty easy to build), can they be used to approximate the infinite sum of $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ for example? Or are they mostly just useful to solve limits...

Answer (score 1):

If you will be encountering sequences and series this is an important one to know:

$$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} =\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}) \rightarrow \infty$$

This is the harmonic sequence, and is very important in determining the convergence of infinite series. The limit can be shown easily using the integral test.

Edit: I also think that this is particularly important:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{A}{n}=0$$ Where $A$ is any real number. Intuitively, this means that an finite number "divided by infinity" will be nothing. That is, a finite quantity, no matter how large, divided by an infinite "quantity" is zero.

Comment: I hate series so much, I never know how to construct them and figure out where they converge and all of that

Comment: I take that back, in early calculus it's actually pretty easy once you've learned all the tests and criterion used to determine convergence and divergence...